# Multiple words to be treated as one word in LetterFx jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-plugins

Been playing around with the LetterFx jQuery Plugin and want to use a particular effect. However, it is setup to do either use individual letters or words for its transitions, where as ultimately, I would like it to use the whole sentence at once. I've tried many different techniques within the HTML, CSS and JS and all have failed. This included trying different modifiers and metacharacters [see below (/S+)/gi; area], as well as, changing the spaces with alternative characters and CSS styles. Was hoping someone might have an idea on what I might be missing on this.

```
var LetterFxConfig = function(conf){
   this.config = $.extend({}, $.fn.letterfx.defaults, conf);
   this.buildCss(this.config.backwards);

   // check & change to word pattern
   if(this.config.words)
        this.config.pattern=/(\S+)/gi;

}
```

I have setup two examples. One of this working normally (with spaces between the words)

http://vectorlyme.github.io/letterfx_issue/default.html

And one how I would like it to work (which can only emulate by removing the spaces, making it one word)

http://vectorlyme.github.io/letterfx_issue/goal.html

Thanks for taking a look!